# How should I partition a 120GB SSD for windows 8 and Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, partitioning

I bought a new SSD 120GB (mistake I know, should've bought a bigger one)  I want to install windows 8 and Ubuntu.  How should I partition it? I'm not planning to save any heavy files (videos, audios etc).  Would be mostly using for programming purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I do on my main machine:

I run windows on the SSD and use the whole partition.  Then I run ubuntu in a Virtualbox VM (free) on the windows machine.  This way you can use both at once, and even share folders to the VM.  There is even a seamless mode (which I don't use) so you can run the ubuntu application windows right along-side your windows application windows.

Comment: This is actually probably the best approach if the system is more powerful than a toaster.  No matter how you partition a drive this size, the partitions will be small enough that you could potentially run into trouble on either side and have to adjust later.

Answer (score 0):

The main question is which one do you plan to use more?  A follow-up to this is what programs do you plan to install on each?  Even though you can install to a different drive, files and registry entries will still end up on the main partition.

If you plan on installing the Adobe Suite, you're going to need a lot of space on the Windows side.  If you're planning on installing programs mostly like Microsoft Office and 'light' programs, you should be good with a 50/50 split.

Answer (score -1):

A careful partitioning scheme should be one that protects your important files from doing OS upgrades, reinstalls, system crashes. I, personally, prefer this scheme:

```
OS1 partition
OS2 partition
...
OSn partition
Data partition
```

In your case that would roughly translate to:

```
Windows 8 30GB
Ubuntu    12GB
Data      78GB (NTFS)
```

All your data should be stored in the Data partition. By making it NTFS (or any fs that Windows recognizes), it will be more likely that Ubuntu can read it, too. If you would like to reallocate different partition sizes for the operating systems, you can manipulate the first 30GB without worrying about the Data partition being touched.

Comment: Trying to run Win 8 on 20GB is probably a bad idea - you might be able to squeeze it on now, but it'll balloon with updates and service packs.

Comment: Unfortunately, 120GB of storage is really not that big, as the OP said, "I'm not planning to save any heavy files (videos, audios etc)". 90GB of storage is too small for that. Of course, he is free to assign a larger partition size.